# Starting device gallery application from my application causes activity to call onCreate again?

Tags: android, android-activity, gallery

In my Android application I have  **EditText**, **TextView**, **ImageView**. And i assign  string value dynamically from `onCreate()` method.

I open the device gallery application by clicking on the `ImageView` (with intent).

But when i get the image URI of gallery selected image via `onActivityResult` method, the assigned value for `TextView` disappears, and my assigned dynamic string value also became null. 'Activity' call `onCreate()` method again.

It happen on some kinds of device (especially those with low RAM). Application works fine in Samsung devices.

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Try to assign this dynamic value in onResume() State.

Comment: How to assign in onResume(using bundle )? @BornToWin

Comment: @Override
public void onResume(){

    // put your code here...

}

Comment: what you can edit in that???